# My first breadboard / led

Tags: led, breadboard

I loosely followed [this](http://hertaville.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/RasberryPiGPIO1.jpg). I've been studying breadboards for about an hour now, so this is super fresh in my head. My understanding is as follows:

- 5v power on the +(red) track (white wire)
- Ground (GND) on the -(bue) track (teal wire)
- p4 (input i'm guessing controller) to the resistor (blue wire)
- resistor to the led
- other side of the led to -(blue track) on ground (black wire)

If I plug this in to my rasp will it blow up?

[image: My Setup]

Comment: What is the 5Volt for there? Do not connect any GPIO to 5V as the GPIO is 0-3.3v sensitive. Like that it should work for 1 LED, not more. It best not to wire things into breadboard if you not going to use them. Like 5V. Just to avoid any mistakes or confusion. Really the power source here is P4 that should go on the + Rail.

Answer (score 4):

No (provided the connecting cable is the right way round).

Even so, if you are that unfamiliar with wiring, You could connect the Pi to the breadboard without connecting the GPIO pin to the Resistor and measure the voltage.

The Pi is not that delicate - the only thing likely to affect the Pi is connecting a GPIO pin to 5v. You are not using the 5v at all in the above.

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

If you really have no idea of what you are doing I'd rather take out the white wire since it plugs to +5V and this is the only thing around that can really damage your raspberry.

If you need a safe constant voltage use the +3V instead (in your picture it is in the bottom, opposite to where you plugged the white wire).